# how to fix "KeyError: 0" in the hugging face transformer train() function

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers, gpt-2, text-generation

hello guys please i am in dying need of your help .
i am trying to fine-tune the gpt2-meduim model with the hugging face transformer and i ran into this error just when i wanted to start the training "KeyError: 0" .
here is my full  code

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
```

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('Train_rev1.csv',error_bad_lines=False, engine='python')
# dataset.head(5)

def replace_string(row):
    row['FullDescription'] = row['FullDescription'].replace('****', str(row['SalaryNormalized']))
    return row

dataset = dataset.apply(replace_string, axis=1)
dataset = dataset.drop(['ContractType','ContractTime','LocationRaw','SalaryRaw','SourceName','Id','Title', 'LocationNormalized', 'Company', 'Category',
       'SalaryNormalized'], axis=1)

dataset.columns

! pip install -q transformers
from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer, GPT2LMHeadModel, Trainer, TrainingArguments
tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('gpt2-medium')
tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': '[PAD]'})
tokenized_data = tokenizer(dataset['FullDescription'].tolist(), truncation=True, padding=True)

# Split data into training and validation sets
train_size = int(0.8 * len(tokenized_data['input_ids']))
val_size = len(tokenized_data['input_ids']) - train_size

train_dataset = {'input_ids': tokenized_data['input_ids'][:train_size],
                 'attention_mask': tokenized_data['attention_mask'][:train_size]}
val_dataset = {'input_ids': tokenized_data['input_ids'][train_size:],
               'attention_mask': tokenized_data['attention_mask'][train_size:]}
```

i beleive my error some how originates around this section

```
from transformers import GPT2Config
# Define model configuration and instantiate model
model_config = GPT2Config.from_pretrained('gpt2-medium')
model_config.output_hidden_states = True
model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained('gpt2-medium', config=model_config)

# Train model using Huggingface Trainer API
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./results',
    num_train_epochs=1,
    per_device_train_batch_size=4,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=4,
    warmup_steps=500,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    logging_dir='./logs',
    logging_steps=10,
    evaluation_strategy='steps',
    eval_steps=50,
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=val_dataset
)

trainer.train()
```

my ide underlines this last statement and produces the the 'KeyError: 0' and it deos not provide me with any other detail about the error apart from

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 trainer.train()

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py in (.0)
49                 data = self.dataset.**getitems**(possibly_batched_index)
50             else:
---> 51                 data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
52         else:
53             data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]

KeyError: 0

i have tried changing some train_arguements but not working and am totally out of ideas as the error is not explicit

Comment: What is in `Train_rev1.csv`, could you provide a sample of it?

Comment: @alvas Train_rev1.csv i a dataset containing job descriptions it contains all the information about the job like [tittle , company name, salary, location, job description, job type etc.